# Trouble with rxvt and Cygwin on Win7 -- what is the difference between rxvt native, unicode xC, unicode xS and x ?

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, rxvt

I'm having difficulties using [RXVT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rxvt) with Cygwin on Win7.

- `rxvt-native` launches properly and i can use it, however, it is *incredibly slow*,
- `rxvt-unicode-xC` doesn't launch at all,
- `rxvt-unicode-xS` seems to launch but then immediately exits,
- `rxvt-x` emphasized text also does nothing.

What is the difference between these 4 RXVT options, and why might `rxvt-native` be running *so slowly* while the other aren't usable at all?

Comment: Not really an answer, but why not try `mintty` instead? It comes standard with Cygwin, doesn't require an X server, and in my (rather extensive) experience it's by far the best Cygwin terminal emulator available.

Comment: I do use mintty, I have for years. It was suggested to me that I give rxvt a try (after complaining about a few things, like modifying the color scheme, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rxvt-native` attempts to run on both Windows and X11 via a rather hack-ish abstraction layer, which is probably the cause for it being slow.  It is unmaintained and deprecated; if you want a Cygwin terminal without X, the default `mintty` shell is recommended.

`rxvt-unicode` is a fork of the original with a more modern codebase and Unicode support, but is an X11 program and therefore requires a running X server in order to operate.  It comes in both standalone (`-xS`) and client/daemon (`-xC` being the client) varieties.